# How to set default Timezone on GORM time.Time data type

Tags: mysql, datetime, go, go-gorm

I am using gorm with mysql as database with go module like this :

- gorm.io/gorm v1.21.7
- github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql v1.6.0

My system timezone is +07:00 (Asia/Jakarta), and the mysql timezone is using the system timezone itself.

but something wrong happen when I've struct like this

```
type Name struct {
    ID         uint64    `gorm:"id;primaryKey;autoIncrement"`
    Name       string    `gorm:"column:name"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time `gorm:"column:created_at"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time `gorm:"column:updated_at"`
}
```

on the mysql table created_at and updated_at declared as **DATETIME**, when I print the CreatedAt and UpdatedAt value, the timezone is +0000 (UTC), when I'm trying to use the [Time.In](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.In) function I got the wrong value, like I'm converting a time from UTC to +07:00, how can I declare to GORM that I'm using +07:00 as default timezone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When connecting to the `MySQL` database, ensure you leverage the `parseTime` and `loc` parameters as per [the docs](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support):

> to scan MySQL DATE and DATETIME values into time.Time variables, which
> is the logical equivalent in Go to DATE and DATETIME in MySQL. You can
> do that by changing the internal output type from []byte to time.Time
> with the DSN parameter parseTime=true. You can set the default
> time.Time location with the loc DSN parameter.

to generate a DSN connection strings to set `parseTime` & `loc` [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966788/1218512) i.e.

```
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Jakarta") // handle any errors!

c := mysql.Config{
    User:                    "....",
    Passwd:                  "....",
    DBName:                  "....",
    Addr:                    "....:3306",
    Net:                     "tcp",
    ParseTime:               true,
    Loc:                     loc,
}
fmt.Println(c.FormatDSN())
```

https://go.dev/play/p/5yoEbmrPqlZ

Comment: does this also work with postgres? I am setting timezone=Europe/Amsterdam to the postgres connection string, but I still see local in the CreatedAt timezone